# Fastest mobile framework for Android?

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, frameworks

I'm tasked with designing a few app style webpages for use on pretty much the cheapest Walmart Android tablet available. I started in jQuery mobile but just a listview with 4 items took 5-6 seconds to load, and it wasn't the connection. Is there a faster mobile framework for Android?

Thanks

Comment: In all seriousness, you may want to post some code that demonstrates how a listview w/ 4 items takes 5-6 seconds.  How are you getting the data?  Is it a service call to get the data?  If so, what does the service-side look like?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried jQuery Mobile and finally quit because of the bad performance too.

I have learned the best is to go bare foot: jQuery (or Zepto.js, it is even faster) on top of Apache Cordova (Phonegap). For simple page transitions in the vein of jQuery mobile I use my own js stuff: https://github.com/grobmeier/Roadcrew.js

This gave me a pretty quick application, even when I have no widgets ready. For that I used Bootstrap btw. When my App grows up I will probably pay somebody to create me a more unique UX experience.